# I have an alignment issue with the candlestick chart in matplotlib which I am buiding from scratch

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to build the candlestick chart from scratch, so that I can do better customization on it. This is the link of the article I used. https://medium.com/swlh/generating-candlestick-charts-from-scratch-ef6e1d3cf0e9

Heres the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np

df = yf.download('adaniports.ns', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')
ap = df.loc['2015-08': '2015-10', :].copy()
ap.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'Adj_close'}, inplace= True)
ap.reset_index(inplace= True)
ap['Days_num'] = ap.Date.apply(lambda x: x - ap.Date[0])
ap.Days_num = ap.Days_num.apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (12, 8))
ax.plot([ap.Days_num, ap.Days_num], [ap.High, ap.Low], color= 'k')
for x in range(len(ap.index)):
    if ap.Close[x] > ap.Open[x]:
     color= 'g'
    else:
     color= 'r'
   rec = mpl.patches.Rectangle((ap.Days_num[x] - 0.25, ap.Open[x]), 0.5, (ap.Close[x] - 
   ap.Open[x]), color= color, zorder= 3)
   ax.add_patch(rec)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Heres the output: [image]

All the candles are not aligned in the middle with the vic properly. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: I used your data to draw a graph in the Colab environment in mplfinance, a library for investments. At a quick glance, they look the same, but what are your challenges?

Comment: I know that its easy and faster to draw candlestick through mpf.plot( ), but the reason I want to build over is because I want to do visual customisation which isn't supported with mpf. Here the issue is that the rectangle patch isn't sitting neatly at the center of the vertical black line. Some are tilted to right, other slightly to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the reason for this alignment issue. Just widening the fig aspect ratio does the trick. I have now changed it to (20, 7) from (12, 8).
That was the only major change I had to do to make it work.
Here is the final output of my custom candlestick chart:
[image]